# how to open another activity class on click of list item of navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am beginner in android. I want to open another activity class NewTest.class onclick of list item of navigation drawer.But I am getting 
/com.navigation E/MainActivity: Error in creating fragment. Kindly tell me What's wrong in this? Thanks.
Here is my code for MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        setupToolbar();

        DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[3];

        drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.connect, "Connect");
        drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.connect, "Fixtures");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        setupDrawerToggle();

    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        ConnectFragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                fragment = new ConnectFragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewTest.class);
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int commit = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    void setupToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    void setupDrawerToggle() {
        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state change.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error log

Comment: Error is in your selectItem method. In case#1, you are not passing any fragment hence when the code reaches the if statement below, it cannot find any fragment initialized and gives the error. Convert your NewTest.class to fragment and initialize it by following way


NewTest testFragment = new NewTest();

Comment: I want to write post method logic in NewTest class so it should be activity. cannot convert it to fragment.Tell me solution over this.

Comment: @RujutaDeshpande try my code  its fullfill your requirement. i knw you get null pointer execetion.

Comment: @RujutaDeshpande hello have you try my posted solution.? please let me update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onNavigationItemSelected() method for that.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.idofYourNavmenu)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToCall.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve like below:

```
  Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_1) {
        fragmentClass = demo1.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_2) {
//pass Activity class where you want to navigate

        fragmentClass=CredentialActivity.class;
    } 

 try {
        if(fragmentClass.newInstance() instanceof Fragment) {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

            if (fragmentClass.getSimpleName().equals("DailyReport")) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_layout, fragment).commit();
                // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
                item.setChecked(true);
                // Set action bar title
                setTitle(item.getTitle());
                // Close the navigation drawer
                drawer.closeDrawers();
            }
        }else
        {
            // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, fragmentClass);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Start Login Activity
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
```